# How to create dir or file in /usr/share/ directory in linux os using c++

Tags: c++, linux

I been working on a linux project for few weeks and for my program I want to save some files to /usr/share/myDir directory. But unfortunately when I use

```
system("mkdir -p /usr/share/myDir")
```

or

```
mkdir("/usr/share/myDir", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH)
```

I am getting user permission denied error.

I been surfing through internet for a solution but unfortunately i am getting some examples showing terminal commands - like using "sudo" to create files or folder in /usr/share directory.

I wonder how other programs create dir to /usr/share/

I am kind of noob to Linux OS. Helps are very much appriciated.

TIA

Comment: Problem is not what command you use, but your account do not have permissions to do so. You can write your own program and run it through `sudo` then you can use either way. By the way why you do not use `mkdir` directly?

Comment: You should not create stuff in there. It is meant to be used by the distribution's package manager and nothing else. Why do you want to create something there? If you want to save e.g. state of your program, it should be saved e.g. in the home folder of the user running the program or the current working directory.

Comment: @user17732522 i want to save some cache files there.

Comment: @Slava i don't want the users of my program to create folder manually to /usr/share/, thats why i don't want to use mkkdir directly.

Comment: @Mirror_Boy047 You should probably adhere to https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html and store such files under `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/myapp` or `~/.cache/myapp`. `/use/share` isn't even meant for system-wide cache, which would be in `/var/cache`.

Comment: Then your program should be owned by root and have SUID and/or SGID bit set on file permissions. Then your program will be able to become root to execute certain commands with super privileges without exposing direct ability to become root to a user.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder how other programs create dir to /usr/share/

Any programs should need **permission** to create a directory to `/usr/share/`.

`/usr/share` has a permission of **755** which means only **root** user can create directory(write operation) in it.

So why we did `sudo` command firstly.

see the [ref](https://ss64.com/bash/sudo.html)